# What is table1.columA REFERENCES table1.columb mean?

Tags: sql-server, reference

```
    HONV NVARCHAR(10),
    TENLOT NVARCHAR(10),
    TEN NVARCHAR(10),
    MANV NVARCHAR(9) PRIMARY KEY,
    NGSINH DATE,
    DCHI NVARCHAR(50),
    PHAI VARCHAR(3) CHECK (PHAI IN('NAM', 'NU')),
    LUONG INT ,
    MA_NQL NVARCHAR(9) REFERENCES dbo.NHANVIEN(MANV), 
    PHG INT 
);
```

I got this code from a Vietnamese website, don't care about the names of the variables, I see here there are `MA_NQL` references to `MANV`, so what does it mean, when it's in the same table?

Comment: It's a `FOREIGN KEY`. Yes, there is some cases when a column referenced by another column in the same table eg: `PersonId` column referenced by `ParentId` column in the same table.

Comment: My guess a weird way to define a foreign key.  Generally a better practice would be to define the column, then write something like `CONSTRAINT FK_<entity>_<some descriptive relation text>_<other entity> FOREIGN KEY (<column(s)>) REFERENCES <other table> (<column(s)>)`

Comment: Why ```MA_NQL``` is a ``FOREIGN KEY```, there is no other table associated with it, so if it is ```FOREIGN KEY```, what is it defining for?

Comment: While a `foreign key` generally points to another table, it _can_ point to the same table. So there is _a_ table associated with that field... This `foreign key` represents a relation between different rows _of the same table_.

Comment: So what is its real effect? I have compared the given answers, and have not found any connection from the 2 columns